# How can I defer Mongoose connection establishment on NestJS app start up?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

I have a NestJS microservice using Mongoose. It has a `/alive` and a `/ready` route to make it usable as a Kubernetes pod.

So it is important that `/alive` gives status 200 when the app is started, even when no MongoDB connection could be established (which gives status 500 on `/ready`). Otherwise Kubernetes would restart the pod, although the pod itself is alive.

But when I start the service without MongoDB running aside, it doesn't start any HTTP listeners (and thus no `/alive` route), waiting on a valid MongoDB connection.

Is it possible to defer the MongoDB connection (e.g. to the first time it's really used) and not require to have a valid connection at app start up?

I asked ChatGPT but it only gives me advice to use an (optionally async) MongooseModuleOptions provider, which is not what it needs here. You can make the Mongoose configuration dynamic this way but not the connection establishment itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@nestjs/mongoose`, then no, it is not possible. The integrated ORM/ODM packages from `@nestjs` assume that you **will** have the database connection ready and available at the start of the application **unless** you are working with `REQUEST` scoped connections, which are handled slightly differently. If you want to use a single connection, but defer it until after the application has started and, you will need to create your own mongoose module that can handle such a feature